# Allow image overflow in "overflow: hidden"-based navigation

Tags: html, css, overflow, hidden

I am trying to rebuild the [Batman Nav](http://codepen.io/MightyShaban/pen/CIfdj) from a left-aligned to a centered logo image. I added an additional li class:

```
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            <li class="logo_nav"><a href="/"><img src="image-url" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
```

and a second logo class to align the logo on the left if the screen size decreases:

```
            <div class="logo_left"><a href="/"><img src="image-url" /></a></div>
```

My problem: The `overflow: hidden;` in the main class does not allow overflow on the centered image. When I delete `overflow: hidden;` from the main class and add the exceptions to the nav classes, the whole design explodes on smaller screens.

Does anyone have an idea on my approach or knows a better way to get the result I need?

See my Pen here: http://codepen.io/akoba/pen/qqEZdX

```js
// Sticky Header
$(window).scroll(function() {

  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
    $('.main').addClass('sticky');
  } else {
    $('.main').removeClass('sticky');
  }
});

// Mobile Navigation
$('.mobile-toggle').click(function() {
  if ($('.main').hasClass('open-nav')) {
    $('.main').removeClass('open-nav');
  } else {
    $('.main').addClass('open-nav');
  }
});

$('.main li a').click(function() {
  if ($('.main').hasClass('open-nav')) {
    $('.navigation').removeClass('open-nav');
    $('.main').removeClass('open-nav');
  }
});

// Navigation Scroll - ljepo radi materem
$('nav a').click(function(event) {
  var id = $(this).attr("href");
  var offset = 70;
  var target = $(id).offset().top - offset;
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: target
  }, 500);
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
.main {
  position: fixed;
  max-height: 85px;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 17px;
  background: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  opacity: 0;
  top: -100px;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 766px) {
  .main {
    padding-top: 25px;
  }
}
.open-nav {
  max-height: 400px !important;
}
.open-nav .mobile-toggle {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
.sticky {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.93);
  opacity: 1;
  top: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gainsboro;
}
.logo_left img {
  max-width: 100px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  overflow: visible;
  margin-left: 20px;
  display: none;
  float: left;
}
.logo_nav img {
  max-width: 130px;
  vertical-align: top;
  overflow: visible !important;
  margin-top: -10px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 766px) {
  .logo_left img {
    display: block;
    overflow: visible;
  }
  .logo_nav {
    display: none;
  }
}
nav {
  width: 100%;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 766px) {
  nav {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 766px) {
  nav ul {
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 22px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 35px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 766px) {
  nav ul li {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 7px 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
}
nav ul a {
  font-size: 12px;
}
.mobile-toggle {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
  right: 22px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  width: 30px;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 766px) {
  .mobile-toggle {
    display: block;
  }
}
.mobile-toggle span {
  width: 30px;
  height: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  border-radius: 1000px;
  display: block;
}
.row {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 940px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 2%;
}
@-webkit-keyframes scroll {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(20px);
    transform: translateY(20px);
  }
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
@keyframes scroll {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(20px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(20px);
    transform: translateY(20px);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="main">
  <div class="logo_left">
    <a href="/">
      <img src="https://c.marketingtechblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/example-logo-660x330.png" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="mobile-toggle">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </div>

    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="logo_nav">
          <a href="/">
            <img src="https://c.marketingtechblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/example-logo-660x330.png" />
          </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 4</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
  sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
  Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos
  et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  <br />
  <br />Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait
  nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
  <br />
  <br />Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla
  facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.
  <br />
  <br />Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam
  erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  <br />
  <br />Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis.
  <br />
  <br />At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et
  dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, At accusam
  aliquyam diam diam dolore dolores duo eirmod eos erat, et nonumy sed tempor et et invidunt justo labore Stet clita ea et gubergren, kasd magna no rebum. sanctus sea sed takimata ut vero voluptua. est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
  amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat.
  <br />
  <br />Consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum
  dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren,
  no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
  et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus.
  <br />
  <br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
  sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
  Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos
  et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  <br />
  <br />Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait
  nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl
  ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril
  delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.
  <br />
  <br />Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam
  erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having `overflow: hidden` on `.main`, add it to the media query.

```
.main {
  position: fixed;
  max-height: 85px;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 17px;
  background: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  opacity: 0;
  top: -100px;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
  overflow: hidden; /*remove from here*/
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 766px) {
  .main {
    padding-top: 25px;
    overflow: hidden; /*add here*/
  }
}
```